# iphone auto lock value?

Tags: iphone, locking

Isn't possible to retrieve auto lock value?
Or anyone know how to modify the auto lock time like those existing alarm application?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to get or set this information. All you can do is set that the device doesn't autosleep while your application is in front, but you will still resign active if the user hits the lock button. You can set the device not to auto-idle by setting the idleTimerDisabled property on the shared instance of UIApplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. you need to implement the following methods

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

This gets called when the phone is locked. In this method I would store the time and then impliment this method on the app delegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

This function will be called when unlocking the phone. Use the time you stored when locking the time to determine how long it has been.

You can use this two methods for custom implementation of auto lock interval.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Jason is right. you can use [application setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]; to stop the autosleep. But there is no way to access the auto lock value.

Regards,
Raxit

Comment: I have see an application called Alarm Clock and in the setting page you are allow to change to auto lock interval. 

Do you guys know how the application can achieve this feature?

Thanks.