# Can I get the auto-lock time in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to custom the auto-lock in my app, and I just find that I can only use the property

"`-(BOOL)idleTimerDisabled`".

When I set the Boolean value, I have to wait for the auto-lock time setting by user in system general setting.
So I need to know the setting, otherwise I cannot control the auto-lock time in my app.
Can i get it?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363051/iphone-auto-lock-value